# How to convert characters into integer in order to stock them in an array in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, char, ascii

I want to stock words gotten from a text in an array according to the first letter in each word.
All words with 'a' will be stocked in the first case words, with 'b' will stocked in the second case...
I don't know how to convert a character into index in order to stock it in the array.

Example:

T[26]

If the first letter in the word is 'a' then this word should be stocked in the first case:

T[1]=word.

To avoid problems I turned the text into minuscule form (lower-case) using the function `strlwr` so all the characters are starting from 97 according to ASCII code.

Comment: arrays start at index 0, so `T[26]` has valid indices 0-25. You can index the array by subtracting `'a'` from letter under test (`'a' - 'a' == 0`, `'b' - 'a' == 1`, etc)

Comment: @yanis In C indices start from 0 not from 1.

Comment: so imma work like this: i=word[1]-'a' / T[i]=word /(word[i] is the first caracter in the word)/  Thank you so much brother

Comment: You don't really have to convert anything.  If `word` is the word you want to place into the array, you want to push the word onto `T[word[0] - 'a']`.  (It's not clear how you're going to "stock" the words.  Is T an array of lists?)

Comment: What do you do if you have both `"apples"` and `"ants"` as words both starting with `'a'`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you want to have an array of wordlists since you have several words
starting with the same letter.

```
struct word
{
  char* text;
  struct word* next;
}

struct word* words[26] = { NULL };
```

so once you find a word, take the first character of that and convert it to an index

```
int index = toupper(someword[0]) - 'A'; // 0..25  since A is ASCII 65

// check if there is any previous words
if (words[index] == NULL)
{
  // first word
  words[index] = malloc(struct word);
  words[index]->text = strdup(someword); // malloc,strcpy
  words[index]->next = NULL;
}
else // e.g. find last word
{
  struct word* last;
  struct word* p;
  
  for ( last = p = words[index]; p != NULL; p = p->next )
  {
    last = p;
  }
  
  assert(last == NULL); // must be at least one
  
  last->next = malloc(struct word);
  last->text = strdup(someword);
  last->next = NULL;
}
```

No you need some function to print all words for an index

at the end, you need to do some clean up all the allocated memory as well.

Comment: EXACTLY that's it

Answer (score -1):

Well you`ll need an array of arrays of words.
And you can use a syntax like this to index the first array:

```
   T['a']=word; //this works only if you have one word beginning with each letter
   T['a'][a_len]=word; //this is what you need to do if you want to have 
                       //an array of words for each letter
```

You can use this becouse 'a' is the a ASCII character, meaning the char with the value 97. But you will have to make sure that T has memory alocated up to index 'z'.

Comment: `T['a']` would probably be out of bounds for `T[26]`. If the encoding is ASCII, as you mentioned `'a'` would be `97` and the maximum index for `T` is `25`.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain how to use the first character of the word as the index.

Comment: well in fact the array is an array of pointers and each pointer of the array point a linked list which contains the words and the thing that i didn't know how to do it is how to transforme the 1st caracter of a word into an integer which represent the case in the array (0,1,2..etc)

Comment: @William Pursell got you the answer, you just do ```T[word[0] - 'a']```

Comment: Thank you guys i tried the solution in the first comment and it worked perfectly